# Counting Weeks between two Jquery Date Pickers

Tags: javascript, jquery

my code mostly works..but occasionally it is giving me really odd decimal numbers. I think it has something to do with UTC time. Any advice?

HTML

```
<h2> First Date</h2>
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="startDate"/>

<h2> Second Date</h2>
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="endDate"/>

<button type="button" id="test">Click It</button>  
<p>Total Weeks</p>
<span id="totalWeeks">HERE</span>
```

JQuery

```
'use strict';

(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#test').click(function () { 
            var end = $('#endDate').datepicker('getDate');
            var start = $('#startDate').datepicker('getDate');
            var $weekDiff = Math.ceil((end - start + 1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / 7;

            $('#totalWeeks').append($weekDiff);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative to doing date arithmetic from scratch, why not use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) which has done all of the hard work for us:

```
  var totalWeeks = moment(end).diff(moment(start), 'weeks');
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wxpak6he/7/)

Comment: Thanks so much. I am still very new at Javascript and Jquery. Would you recommend a new learner jump right into moment.js before getting a solid grasp on how to use these?

Comment: I want work to building something where once the two dates are selected,you  the start and end of each week within the selected range.  Ex) December 28 2014 and January 10 2015 : week 1- December 28 2014-January 3 2014 week 2 January 4 2014 January 10 2014. I realize the first step is getting the total weeks, next step is the addition of each week.

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of weeks between two dates you need to round result of division by `7` with `floor`:

```
var $weekDiff = Math.floor((end - start + 1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / 7);
```

#### Test it: http://jsfiddle.net/jafaoej5/